# Prime ideals $\mathfrak{p} \supset \mathfrak{a}$ are finite in one-dimensional Noetherian domain

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, noetherian

Let $A$ be a one-dimensional Noetherian domain. Let $\mathfrak{a} \neq 0$ be an ideal of $A$. How do I prove that prime ideals $\mathfrak{p} \supset \mathfrak{a}$ are finite?

Thanks.

Comment: It could be helpful if you shared your thoughts and attempts... Anyway, are you familiar with Artinian rings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quotient ring $A/\mathfrak a$ is zero-dimensional and noetherian, so it is artinian. But artinian rings have finitely many maximal ideals.